# ConTeXt: Calculate Page Number as Percentage of Page Count

Tags: page-numbering, context, width, calculations

## Background

Looking to draw a horizontal "progress bar" along the bottom of each page. The first page should have no line above the page number (or very, very short) and the last page should have a line `\textwidth` in length.

## Code

The following code works in some but not all situations:

```
% Calculate the percentage complete for a progress meter.
\define\PercentComplete{\the\dimexpr\textwidth*\currentpage/\lastpage\relax}

%
\define\PageNumber{%
  \inframed[
    frame=off,
    bottomframe=on,
    width=\PercentComplete,
    framecolor=ProgressBar,
  ]{\currentpage\ of \lastpage}
}

\startsetups[FooterLeft]
  \midaligned{\FontFooter \PageNumber}
\stopsetups

\startsetups[FooterRight]
  \midaligned{\FontFooter \PageNumber}
\stopsetups
```

## Example Output

Here are some examples that work using the above code:

[image: Page 4 of 145]

[image: Page 61 of 145]

[image: Page 144 of 145]

Other documents, unfortunately, fail with an arithmetic error (probably divide by zero).

## Question

What is the correct way to calculate the percentage complete so that if `\lastpage` isn't valid (i.e., first pass of multiple passes), then the calculation is postponed until `\lastpage` has a known value?

Comment: `\ifnum\lastpage=0 \else .. \fi`?

Comment: If you want much fancier "progress bars", see my [visualcounter](https://github.com/adityam/visualcounter) module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macro `\lastpage` is 0 during the first pass because the document's last page is unknown. This allows setting the percentage to 0pt for the first pass and to the desired dimension for all other passes. Also, measures provide a higher-level interface to adaptive dimensions.

```
\doifelse{\lastpage}{0}{
  \definemeasure
    [percent complete]
    [0pt]
}{
  \definemeasure
    [percent complete]
    [\textwidth*\currentpage/\lastpage]
}

\define\PageNumber{%
  \inframed[
    frame=off,
    bottomframe=on,
    width=\measure{percent complete},
    framecolor=ProgressBar,
  ]{\currentpage\ of \lastpage}
}

\def\FontFooter{\ss}

\startsetups[FooterLeft]
  \midaligned{\FontFooter \PageNumber}
\stopsetups

\startsetups[FooterRight]
  \midaligned{\FontFooter \PageNumber}
\stopsetups

\setupfootertexts[\setups{FooterLeft}][\setups{FooterRight}]

\starttext

\dorecurse{10}{\input knuth\relax}

\stoptext
```

Comment: For some reason, this only works if the `.tuc` file is deleted prior to running `context`. If the `.tuc` file remains, the measure is only set once: to `\zeropoint`.

Comment: @DaveJarvis You are right.  Apparently, the mode `*first` is always active when you run ConTeXt and is only disabled when ConTeXt itself decides to run multiple passes.